# SharePoint Online URL Differences

Tags: office365, sharepoint

I have recently taken over management of a SharePoint Online based intranet. I noticed that many of the existing sites have a home page URL formatted like:

```
https://companyname.sharepoint.com/pagename/SitePages/Home.aspx
```

All new pages I create have a home page URL formatted like:

```
https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/pagename
```

What causes these differences, and why do some URLs appear to specify a particular .aspx file, while others do not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you call "pagename" in your first URL is not a page. It is the name of a sub site nested under the root site collection and that link goes to the home page of the sub site.

The second link is to a site collection that is independent of the root site, and again, pagename is the wrong term. It is a site name.

The first URL is part of a hierarchy of sites, like the two connected sites on the left of the image. The URLs that have "sites" after the tenant sharepoint name are not in a hierarchy relationship to the root site.

[image]